# Automatically framing (or drawing the bounding box of ) a PStricks non-text object 

Tags: pstricks, framed

Is there a command or macro that can draw and automatically size the bounding rectangle of a `pstricks` object, for example a circle -- framing it tightly in effect, even when the object undergoes transformations such as rotations.

For example,

```
     \documentclass[english, landscape, a4paper]{slides}
     \usepackage{pstricks}

    \begin{pspicture}(1,-1)(20,17) 
        \pscircle(5,5){2} % I'd like to draw the bounding box of this object
    \end{pspicture}
```

Edit: the difficulty that I'm having is calculating the dimensions of the frame or bounding box.

Comment: In your title you mention "graphic", while your post refers to "object". These can be interpreted differently. Therefore, does "object" refer to the entire contents of your `pspicture`, or merely an object like some text?

Comment: I've changed graphic to non-text graphic, for example a circle of radius 2 i.e. `\pscircle(5,5){2}`

Comment: You should create _complete_ examples, then everybods knows what _exactly_ you are asking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\psframebox[shadow,framesep=...,...]{%
  pstricks object with a pspicture environment
}
```

or if you do not have it *outside* of the pspicture environment

```
\documentclass[english, landscape, a4paper]{slides}
\usepackage{pstricks} \SpecialCoor
\makeatletter
\def\psCircleSquare{\pst@object{psCircleSquare}}
\def\psCircleSquare@i(#1)#2{{%
  \use@par
  \rput(#1){\psframe(!#2 neg dup)(!#2 dup)}%
  \pscircle(#1){#2}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5}
\begin{pspicture}(1,-1)(20,17) 
  \psCircleSquare[shadow](5,5){2} 
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The framebox is tiny and at the origin. Here's what I tried     `\psframebox[shadow]{\pscircle(5,5){2}}`

Comment: sure, as I wrote: If you'd provide a _complete_ example then it is possible to give a correct answer. See my edit.

Comment: I apologize. I realize that I haven't made myself clear enough.  I was hoping for a command that could automatically frame an object, without having to specify its dimensions. The problem I'm having is in computing the dimensions of the frame, for my objects some of who undergo transformations such as rotation.

Comment: @Olumide: It is pretty simple, but only when I know what exactly you want. And now I know it, see edited answer

Comment: Thanks @Herbert ("You da man"). I'll try generalizing the macro for arbitrary objects.

Comment: OOps. The circle was a horrible example. I've just realized that the macro does not seem to help create a bounding frame or box for an arbitrarily rotated rectangle.

Comment: I must think about it, but I am away from home until mid of next week.

Comment: Thanks. Next week would probably be too late for the present purposes. However such a feature would make a nice addition to PSTricks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1462/discussion-between-olumide-and-herbert)