# pslegend bounding box odd while using Cirkuit

Tags: pstricks, legend, bounding-box, pst-plot

This question is regarding `pst-plot` and more specifically `\pslegend`. The code below produces the two following plots:

[image]
[image]

One of these figures is generated without the `\pslegend` and it appears to have the correct bounding box. The figure which includes the `\pslegend` appears not to have the correct bounding box.

The two `.txt` data files can be found [at this address](http://www.iceamplifiers.co.uk/latex/).

Could anyone explain what I have done to cause this? I'm on pdfTeX, version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)

The code which surrounds everything from the first `\readdata` to `\end{psgraph}` is lifted from Cirkuit's pstricks wrapper (see http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/?content=107098). Cirkuit is a Qt GUI front end for preparation of circuit diagrams pstricks and TikZ diagrams.

I'm fairly sure it's something in the wrapper commands that's giving me problems, not the pstricks stuff.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multido,pst-all,graphicx,amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\newbox\graph
\begin{TeXtoEPS}
\readdata{\ihigh}{halfwavehighimpedanceid.txt}
\readdata{\ilow}{halfwavelowimpedanceid.txt}

% Remove this \pslegend in the correct box example...
\pslegend[rt]{\blue\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & $I_D$ Lower Z\\
\red\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & $I_D$ Higher Z
}

\psset{llx=-1cm,lly=-1cm, xAxisLabel={Time [ms]}, xAxisLabelPos={c,-0.3in}, yAxisLabel={Voltage [V]}, yAxisLabelPos={-0.3in,c}}

\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=axes,xticksize=0 10,yticksize=0 50,subticks=0,Dx=10, Dy=2, Oy=0](0,0)(50,10){7cm}{5cm}
\pstScalePoints(1e3,1e0){}{}
\listplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt]{\ilow}
\listplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt]{\ihigh}

\end{psgraph}

\box
\graph
\end{TeXtoEPS}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. Also, it's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: Thank you for making the question look neater than I did. I will take note of what you have said for the future.

Comment: I've decided it's not a bounding box problem because the answer to [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29747/automatically-framing-or-drawing-the-bounding-box-of-a-pstricks-non-text-obje] allows me to see the bounding box.

Comment: When I generate a dvi of some pstricks (including the above code) by calling (latex on it), and then run `dvips -E input.dvi -o output.eps` my output eps also has a white space on the lhs of the drawing (as per the original question). I'm no closer to knowing if it's a dvips, latex or pstricks problem. But I do know it's not a Cirkuit problem. My dvips version is dvips(k) 5.992.

Comment: I came up against this again tonight, and it felt familiar somehow. I still don't know why it happens but using for example: `\pslegend[r](50,50){\blue\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & $I_D$ Lower Z\\
\red\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & $I_D$ Higher Z` Seems to do the trick. The 50 and 50 are x and y axis offset respectively. I'd still like to know why using tr and lt as the reference cause problems whereas using r and l do not. Perhaps @Herbert could explain it?

Comment: I cannot see any difference in the two images??

Answer (score 1):

Running it with xelatex and an up-to-date TeXLive:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\readdata{\ihigh}{/tmp/halfwavehighimpedanceid.txt}
\readdata{\ilow}{/tmp/halfwavelowimpedanceid.txt}

\psset{llx=-1cm,lly=-1cm, xAxisLabel={Time [ms]}, 
       xAxisLabelPos={c,-0.3in}, yAxisLabel={Voltage [V]}, 
       yAxisLabelPos={-0.3in,c}}

\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=axes,xticksize=0 10,yticksize=0 50,
       subticks=0,Dx=10, Dy=2,Oy=0](0,0)(50,10){7cm}{5cm}
  \pstScalePoints(1e3,1){}{}
  \listplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt]{\ilow}
  \listplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt]{\ihigh}
\end{psgraph}

\pslegend[rt]{\blue\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & $I_D$ Lower Z\\
    \red\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & $I_D$ Higher Z
}

\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=axes,xticksize=0 10,yticksize=0 50,
      subticks=0,Dx=10, Dy=2,Oy=0](0,0)(50,10){7cm}{5cm}
  \pstScalePoints(1e3,1){}{}
  \listplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt]{\ilow}
  \listplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt]{\ihigh}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]